# Why svn update discard local changes?

Tags: svn

I've found that some of my local changes are gone after

> svn up

Why could it happen ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`svn update`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.update.html) command never discards or removes local changes made in your working copy. Maybe you ran the [`svn revert`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.revert.html) command instead? Or is there a conflict? What does [`svn status`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html) show?

Updating your working copy fetches the latest changes from your repository and does not remove your local modifications. If the incoming changes conflict with your local ones, there will be a conflict. SVN offers you to resolve this conflict interactively or manually.